# Option Strict On, set Focus of unknown object type

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am updating some code to allow for Option Strict On.  One issue that is coming up, is late binding.  I have a `Form` with multiple required items of different types (`TextBox`, `ComboBox`, etc.).. I have a function to check the validity of the `Form`, and then set the focus to the first control that doesn't have a value.

Without Option Strict On, I could simply have a basic `Object`, and set that to whichever control was missing a value, and then call `objMissing.Focus()` at the end, but with Option Strict On, the compiler doesn't allow the late binding.

I realize that if the controls were all the same type, I could cast the missing object to a `TextBox`, for example.  Is there a way I can still do this using one variable to store the control to set focus to?  Or should I just set the Focus immediately in each of the `If`s that are checking for a value?

Here is an example of the code I am looking at (txt_ are `TextBox`, cbo_ are `ComboBox`, btn_ are `Button` types):

```
    Dim objMissing as Object

    If txtItemDescription.Text = String.Empty Then
        objMissing = txtItemDescription
        strMessage = "You must enter an item description."
    ElseIf cboProductType.Text = String.Empty Then
        objMissing = cboProductType
        strMessage = "You must select a product type."
    ElseIf cboComponentType.Text = String.Empty And cboComponentType.Enabled Then
        objMissing = cboComponentType
        strMessage = "You must select a component type."
    ElseIf txtOnHand.Text = String.Empty Then
        txtOnHand.Text = "0"
    ElseIf txtRented.Text = String.Empty Then
        txtRented.Text = "0"
    ElseIf txtCost.Text = String.Empty Then
        txtCost.Text = "0.00"
    ElseIf txtFreight.Text = String.Empty Then
        txtFreight.Text = "0.00"
    ElseIf Len(txtBarcodePrefix.Text) < 6 Then
        objMissing = txtBarcodePrefix
        strMessage = "You must enter a 6-digit barcode prefix."
    ElseIf cboCondition.Text = String.Empty Then
        objMissing = cboCondition
        strMessage = "You must enter a condition."
    ElseIf btnComponents.Enabled And Me.ComponentList.Count = 0 Then
        objMissing = btnComponents
        strMessage = "You must select the item components."
    ElseIf txtSerialNumber.Text <> String.Empty AndAlso txtOnHand.Text <> String.Empty Then
        If CInt(txtOnHand.Text) > 1 Then
            objMissing = txtOnHand
            strMessage = "You cannot have more than 1 item on hand with the same serial number."
        End If
    End If

    If objMissing IsNot Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show(strMessage)
        objMissing.Focus()
    End If
```

Comment: Is this winform, asp.net, wpf?

Comment: Ah sorry, added the winforms tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare objMissing as type Control, then your code will work as you want. All standard WinForms controls should inherit from Control.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  I was getting too general with the `Object` type, but `Control` did the trick.  Thank you.

Comment: Just to add that if this happens in future, look at the object hierarchy either through MSDN (eg [Textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx)) or VS's object browser... Follow up the tree until you find the object that's as generic/specific as you need